# Struts jQuery UI Accordion - Disable enter/space keypress

Tags: jquery, struts, jquery-ui-accordion

i'm trying to disable the enter key/spacebar press event for my accordion that is implemented using the struts jquery plugin.  I found some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511785/jquery-ui-accordion-and-space-bar-problem) about how to possibly do this by modifying the accordion js file, but i can't seem to find the accordion js file.  Is it dynamically generated when the code is built?  I have a struts jquery jar, but didn't find the accordion js inside of it.

Thanks in advance for any direction you can provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In [this article](http://www.jgeppert.com/2011/02/how-to-overwrite-functions-in-struts2-jquery-plugin/) explain how to overwrite the functions struts jquery plugin:

```
 <sj:head />
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.struts2_jquery.autocompleter = function($elem, options) {
alert("my own autocompleter handler for "+options.id);
   };
 </script>
```

Comment: i saw this, but wasn't exactly sure what it meant.  How can i tailor this to suit the purpose of disabling the enter/space keypress?

Comment: Well, i actually ended up resolving this without having to deal with overwriting the keypress function by just setting the collapsible property of the accordion to false, effectively disallowing any opened accordion items from closing without something else opening in its place.  Since the user now does not have the ability to close it using a keypress, they also won't have the ability to open it using a keypress either.  :)