# Cannot press space into text field, jquery ui bug?

Tags: jquery

not sure if this bug caused buy jquery ui tab, I at first thought was my keydown function error

```
function inputKeydown(e) {
    var $this = $(e.target).closest('input[type="text"]');

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $this.blur();
    }
}
```

but it's not..

http://jsfiddle.net/TyfK7/

Comment: Space bar works fine on your fiddle here, using FF22

Comment: That is not a bug, that is a feature of the plugin for some reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511785/jquery-ui-accordion-and-space-bar-problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum it up, easiest solution would be to use this (e.g. on ready-event):

```
delete($.ui.tabs.prototype._tabKeydown);
```

And the 'forbidden' keys (space and arrows) should work now. pay atention that it could cause other problems.

**EDIT**

AFAIK, following solves the same problem without errors:

```
$.widget( "ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    _tabKeydown: function(e) {
        this._super( '_tabKeydown' );
    }
});
```