# Input box in jQuery UI Accordion Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery UI accordion with input box on header:

```
<h3><input type="text" /></h3>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7VN8h/

As expected, Accordion catches all space and arrow keypresses, that take place within header - so it's not possible to write into input box correctly. Is there any way to get rid from this behaviour, and use space and arrows, when typing there?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm able to enter input into the text field fine.

Comment: Check this question and the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511785/jquery-ui-accordion-and-space-bar-problem

Comment: Yes, I'm able to enter some text into the text box, but it's not possible to enter space; and to use arrow keys to navigate within text. Arun's answer solves this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stop the propagation of key events from the input control

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

    $("#accordion h3 input").on('keydown', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nyCLm/)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to be able to enter input into the text field without triggering the accordion element, add this:

```
$('input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7VN8h/)**

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked well for me:

```
$('#TSResultContent input[type="textbox"]').keydown(function (e)  {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```